# Mysql concat doesn't work if a column is null, what is wrong with the query?

Tags: mysql, sql

Consider this Mysql query:

```
SELECT user.monitored_user_id, user.firstName, user.lastName, user.username, type1.name, group1.group_name 
FROM monitored_users_tbl user, group_tbl group1, user_type_tbl type1 
WHERE CONCAT(firstName , ' ' , lastName) LIKE CONCAT('%', 'alex', '%') AND user.group_id = group1.group_id AND user.user_type_id = type1.user_type_id
```

This works fine when there is a first **and** last name. But if last name is null, this returns nothing.
Why is that?

Is it because MySQL transforms null into a string or something? How can I fix it?

Comment: Why are you choosing not to use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax?

Comment: The question is badly asked, it lacks a [example].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So much wrong here :(

- The `TableA, TableB` join syntax has been obsolete for 25 years now. *Stop using it.*
- Concatenating these values is the slowest way possible to make this comparison, because it breaks matching to any index that might have helped the query.
- With standard SQL, `NULL` plus `NULL` is still... `NULL`. Remember, `NULL` means "I don't know", and when you concatenate "I don't know" with something else, you still *don't know* what the result will be. MySql has done of poor job of this behavior over the years, but this is how it's supposed to be.

Try this:

```
SELECT user.monitored_user_id, user.firstName, user.lastName, user.username, type1.name, group1.group_name 
FROM monitored_users_tbl user 
INNER JOIN group_tbl group1 ON user.group_id = group1.group_id
INNER JOIN user_type_tbl type1 ON user.user_type_id = type1.user_type_id
WHERE firstName LIKE CONCAT('%', 'alex', '%') 
    OR lastName LIKE CONCAT('%', 'alex', '%')
```

Even better if you can use a computed column and a full-text index, or can remove the leading wildcard.

If you *really* want that all in one comparison (again, it'll tend to be slower), you can do this:

```
WHERE CONCAT(coalesce(firstName,'') , ' ' , coalesce(lastName,'')) LIKE CONCAT('%', 'alex', '%')
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for this great answer. I know this query is really ugly. didn't know the inner join syntax is more optimized. Thanks!

Comment: Not necessarily more optimized. It's just the newer (if you can call something published in 1992 "new") and clearer way to express the same thing. There are certain things that can't be expressed using the old syntax, and this is what dbas expect to see now.

Comment: In the book [SQL Performance Tuning](https://www.amazon.com/SQL-Performance-Tuning-Peter-Gulutzan/dp/0201791692/) the authors tested the different join syntax forms in all the major commercial and open-source RDBMS products, and found no performance difference. Regardless of the syntax to invoke the join, the execution of the query undoubtedly uses the same code. But the SQL-92 syntax supports new types of joins like outer joins, whereas the older syntax doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat says:

> CONCAT() returns NULL if any argument is NULL.

Why is this? In general, operations on an "unknown" value return an "unknown" result.

Example: Suppose I don't tell you my middle name. Someone asks you for Bill's middle name. You can only say, "sorry, I don't know it."

Then that person asks you what is Bill's first name concatenated with Bill's middle name. What could you answer?

---

To solve this in your case, you could replace a NULL string with `''`, a zero-length string, which is not the same as NULL (at least if you're not using Oracle database).

You can put the string into a function like [COALESCE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) or [IFNULL()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/flow-control-functions.html#function_ifnull).

```
WHERE CONCAT(IFNULL(firstName, ''), ' ' , IFNULL(lastName, '')) LIKE ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try `COALESCE` like

```
WHERE CONCAT(COALESCE(`firstName`,'') , ' ' , COALESCE(`lastName`,'')) LIKE CONCAT('%', 'alex', '%')
```